# Empty Values in difference between rows using OVER functions in IF/Case-when statement

Tags: spotfire

I have these columns:

Product, Price, Date

I also created a "Rank" - Rank([Product]) - column to assign an ID for each element.

What I want is to calculate a column with the price difference between two product in the same date.

Let's say I want to calculate difference between apples and bananas where apples rank is 1 and bananas rank is 2.

I found that with this expression

```
First([Price]) OVER (Intersect([Date], FirstNode([Rank]))) - First([Price]) OVER (Intersect([Date], Next(FirstNode([Rank]))))
```

I'm able to achieve the desired result but when I try to put this expression in a IF/Case when statement like this,

```
If([Product]='Apples', First([Price]) OVER (Intersect([Date], FirstNode([Rank]))) - First([Price]) OVER (Intersect([Date], Next(FirstNode([Rank])))), null)
```

I get only a blank column and I can't figure out why.
Can somebody explain me this or suggest other ways to get same results? Actually the only solution I found is to calculate a column  for apple's prices and another one for bananas prices, only then I can do the difference between these values in a If statement, but doing 3 calculated column in order to get 1 is not what I want.